# Is `MPI_COMM_WORLD` a bad idea if only pairs of ranks ever communicate?

Tags: mpi, scalability

I have very little experience with MPI, so please forgive the naïveté of this question.

I have what I thought was a relatively simple MPI program: a large amount of independent tasks need to be computed, and assembled into a certain array. I do this by letting all ranks talk to rank 0, requesting new entries to compute, and reporting the result back to rank 0. Each communication is of the order of just hundreds of bytes, and always happens between rank 0 and any one of the other ranks. Is it a bad idea to keep all the ranks in the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator in such a setup? Should I split into a bunch of separate communicators consisting or rank 0 & 1, rank 0 & 2, rank 0 & 3, … , rank 0 & n? Or is it OK to stay in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` as long as all communications just go to one other rank anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Communicators are heavy-weight objects. Creating a new communicator takes time and consumes internal MPI resources.

It is better to create new communicators for the following cases:

- When different abstraction layers within your application need “safe”
  communication scopes.
- When you need to subset the processes from a
  parent communicator (e.g., you have a significant operation that only
  needs to be performed by half the processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`).
- When you need to re-order the processes from a parent communicator
  (e.g. your MPI processes have a logical ordering that is different
  than their “native” `MPI_COMM_WORLD` rank).

In short: Only create new communicators when you need a whole new/safe communication scope, or you need to change your existing scope (e.g., subset and/or reorder the member processes).

Reference: [Here](https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/which-to-use-tags-or-communicators)

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't every send- and receive-like operation require a communicator?

Comment: does replacing "use communicators when" with "only create new communicators when" makes you less confused?

Comment: @gspr Yes communicator is necessary. I was talking about creating new communicators. Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: Yes, thank you. I'm still confused about one thing though: if a send/receive with just one sender & recipient occurs, is there a penalty from this happening with a communicator that has thousands of members?

Comment: This is theoretically implementation dependent. That being said, I do not expect a significant penalty if any.